# What's the meaning of the letter ,,s" at the end of the word good in the following sentence ? (Also what is the entire meaning of it ?)

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

It's an excerpt from the movie "The Shining"
Jack Torrance: You've had your whole fu**ing life to think things over, what good's a few minutes more gonna do you now?

Comment: What good is a (period of) a few more minutes going to do you?

Comment: quotation marks in English are “ ... ”  not ,, ... "  It's easy to forget this kind of thing when writing, but it makes your punctuation look completely alien.

Comment: Yeah, i know, sorry. It's funny that you mention this because i learned about that literally in the middle of writing that post(as you can see, only the title has differently styled quotes). I read on the internet that only some parts of Europe use bottom quote sing and that's why it's not on any keybord(i was always using double comma for that).I'll stop doing it now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"what good's" is a contraction for "what good is." Contractions are common in speech.

The meaning is: "If you have not been able to come to a conclusion after thinking about something for your entire adult life, you are extremely unlikely to reach a conclusion in the next few minutes."

Comment: Hmm, i was suspecting it would be that(and it's bad because it will be hard to understand, for me), but it's phrased in an odd way to me . For example, a sentence like this: "what good is a few minutes more if the job will take hours"-is perfectly comprehensible to me. Or if the sentence from the movie was written with two sentences like this: "what good's a few minutes more ? What is it  gonna do you now?"-would make sense as well. It's as if between the words "more" & "gonna" something is missing to make logical sense for me.

Comment: I do not say it is elegant speech, but it is quite common colloquial speech.

Comment: Perhaps i don't understand what "gonna do you now" means. I know it can be spelled      
" going to do you now" but whether it's the same as "going to do for you" i don't know

Comment: Yes. It means "what are a few minutes going to do for you now." That "do you now" is uneducated or very careless speech.